# How do I combine Connect middleware into one middleware?

Tags: node.js, middleware, node.js-connect

I have a few middlewares that I want to combine into one middleware. How do I do that?

For example:

```
// I want to shorten this...
app.use(connect.urlencoded())
app.use(connect.json())

// ...into this:
app.use(combineMiddleware([connect.urlencoded, connect.json]))

// ...without doing this:
app.use(connect.urlencoded()).use(connect.json())
```

I want it to work dynamically -- I don't want to depend on *which* middleware I use.

I feel like there's an elegant solution other than a confusing `for` loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you like fancy stuff, here is one of possible solutions:

```
var connect = require('connect')
var app = connect()

function compose(middleware) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    connect.apply(null, middleware.concat(next.bind(null, null))).call(null, req, res)
  }
}

function a (req, res, next) {
  console.log('a')
  next()
}

function b (req, res, next) {
  console.log('b')
  next()
}

app.use(compose([a,b]))

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.end('Hello!')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Here is what it does: `compose` function takes array of middleware and return composed middleware. `connect` itself is basically a middleware composer, so you can create another connect app with middlewares you want: `connect.apply(null, middleware)`. Connect app is itself a middleware, the only problem is that it doesn't have a `next()` call in the end, so subsequent middleware will be unreachable. To solve that, we need another `last` middleware, which will call `next` : `connect.apply(null, middleware.concat(last))`. As last only calls `next` we can use `next.bind(null, null)` instead. Finally, we call resulting function with `req` and `res`.

Comment: Nice, but I'd argue it's more confusing that the loop that the OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: the idea is to abstract composition as a function, implementation is secondary. by the way, here is a package (doesn't depend on connect): https://www.npmjs.org/package/connect-compose

Answer (score 29):

Express accepts arrays for [`app.use`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.use) if you have a path:

```
var middleware = [connect.urlencoded(), connect.json()];
app.use('/', middleware)
```

However, if you want a generic `combineMiddleware` function, you can build  a helper easily without any additional libraries. This basically takes advantage of the fact that `next` is simply a function which takes an optional error:

```
/**
 * Combine multiple middleware together.
 *
 * @param {Function[]} mids functions of form:
 *   function(req, res, next) { ... }
 * @return {Function} single combined middleware
 */
function combineMiddleware(mids) {
  return mids.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
      a(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        b(req, res, next);
      });
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Passing an array works with Express, doesn't work with Connect (without Express).

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but the need is still frequent for all the things using middlewares, like connect, express or custom made req/res/next patterns.

This is a very elegant and purely functional solution:

File **./utils/compose-middleware.js**:

```
function compose(middleware) {
  if (!middleware.length) {
    return function(_req, _res, next) { next(); };
  }

  var head = middleware[0];
  var tail = middleware.slice(1);

  return function(req, res, next) {
    head(req, res, function(err) {
      if (err) return next(err);
      compose(tail)(req, res, next);
    });
  };
}

module.exports = compose;
```

The final result of the `compose(middlewareList)` is a single middleware that encapsulates the whole chain of middleware initially provided.

Then simply import it and use like this:

File **app.js**:

```
var connect = require('connect');
var compose = require('./utils/compose-middleware');

var middleware = compose([
  connect.urlencoded(),
  connect.json()
]);

var app = connect();
app.use(middleware);
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple and native way, and you don't need to install anything.

```js
const {Router} = require('express')

const combinedMiddleware = Router().use([middleware1, middleware2, middleware3])
```

Then you can use the `combinedMiddleware` where you want. For example, you may want to run different set of middlewares/handlers for the same route depending on some conditions (a request attributes, for example):

```js
app.get('/some-route', (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.someParam === 'someValue'
    ? combinedMiddleware1(req, res, next)
    : combinedMiddleware2(req, res, next)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a library:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/middleware-flow

```
var series = require('middleware-flow').series;
var app = require('express')();

app.use(series(mw1, mw2, mw2)); // equivalent to app.use(mw1, mw2, mw3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list and use a loop.

```js
const connect = require('connect')
const { urlencoded, json } = require('body-parser')

const app = connect()

[ urlencoded(), json() ].forEach(app.use, app)
```

The second argument of `.forEach` is used for `this`, but if you like you can also do the same with:

```js
[ urlencoded(), json() ].forEach(app.use.bind(app))
```